# Admin Sidebar came "out of nowhere" and make the interface crash

Tags: django

I haven't add anything uncommon to my installed apps and didn't touch my admin.py file, here are the screens : ( it's normal looking on firefox and completly broken on chromium as you can see )

I remember downloading django-database-size but I immediately used pip-autoremove and haven't made any change to my settings.py/admin.py , do any of you know where it could possibly come from cause I'm still confused?  Thanks in advance , here is my virtual environment pip list just in case :

https://0bin.net/paste/e2UE4m3MF0EUaVhn#21bllXwBKbCpGrNVxX6jVBmBw1AB1yQu-po5zCI6WSh

[image: chromium]

[image: firefox]

Comment: share your settings.py installed apps section

Comment: I should precise it's not due to 'django_admin_listfilter_dropdown' , I of course suspected it but removing it from installed_apps + removing the package didn't make disappear the sidebar : https://pastebin.com/mmKJnWJN

Comment: open in incognito mode, see whether any difference

Comment: In an Incognito tab i get the same looking in Chromium as i get in Firefox ( no messy interface ) but i still get the sidebar and can't figure out from where it comes, deleting cache in normal mode made the sidebar look normal btw

Answer (score 0):

Please run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

and re-run the server by

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Don't forget to close all browser windows and clear the browser cache.

Comment: didn't change anything

Comment: i mean i don't want this sidebar to look good on chromium, clearing cache solved this problem as i said above, I want to know where this sidebar come form since i don't think i have anything fancy in my installed_apps and admin.py

Comment: During a minute I thought i was crazy and that bar was here by default in the django admin  but fortunaetly not

Comment: So as i already mentioned in my answer to delete the cache could solve your problem you may mark my answer as correct for any new comer in the future.

Comment: I had already delete the cache before your comment ( and commented it )  + it didn't solve my problem at all, the problem is 'where is this sidebar coming from ? '